# How to set password complexity in redhat 7.5?

Tags: linux, redhat

I am  trying to set a password policy complexity on red-hat 7.5.
i want that every user that will try to change his password will have to use password with at least - (1 Lower , 1 Upper , 1 Digit , 1 Special Char ) and at least 15 chars long.

Comment: How do you mean, "nothing directs to the right path while using the new **pwquality** module? What have you tried? The man page (https://linux.die.net/man/5/pwquality.conf) lists options like classes and minimum length.

Comment: Hello,Sorry for the mistyping.

Comment: I meant directs to the right answer, I mean using the new pwquality module.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you're trying to say. :-(

Comment: I would have used `bBqwfiRb9rHuW1rOu8UCiTie1HgiIbR6` as my password. But your policy would reject it, so now I'll have to go with `Aa00aa00aa00aa.` instead.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments: have you read the man page for [pwquality.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/pwquality.conf)? It sounds like you only need to add these two lines:

```
minlen = 15
minclass = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

(I don't have a RHEL 7 system at hand, only a CentOS 7 which is usually identical, except when subtly different. )

By default the pwquality PAM module is already enabled and you only need to adjust the default policy in the configuration file [`/etc/security/pwquality.conf`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-pwquality.conf/) to suit your needs.

```
 # /etc/security/pwquality.conf
 # Minimum acceptable size for the new password (plus one if
 # credits are not disabled which is the default). (See pam_cracklib manual.)
 # Cannot be set to lower value than 6.
 minlen = 15
 # The minimum number of required classes of characters for the new
 # password (digits, uppercase, lowercase, others).
 minclass = 4
```

Alternatively you can tune the password policy with the `authconfig` command:

```
authconfig --help 
  ...
  --passminlen=<number>
                        minimum length of a password
  --passminclass=<number>
                        minimum number of character classes in a password
  --passmaxrepeat=<number>
                        maximum number of same consecutive characters in a password
  --passmaxclassrepeat=<number>
                        maximum number of consecutive characters of same class in a password
    --enablereqlower        require at least one lowercase character in a password
    --disablereqlower       do not require lowercase characters in a password
    --enablerequpper        require at least one uppercase character in a password
    --disablerequpper       do not require uppercase characters in a password
    --enablereqdigit        require at least one digit in a password
    --disablereqdigit       do not require digits in a password
    --enablereqother        require at least one other character in a password
    --disablereqother       do not require other characters in a password
    --enablefaillock        enable account locking in case of too many consecutive authentication failures
    --disablefaillock       disable account locking on too many consecutive authentication failures
   ...
```

i.e. something along the lines of

```
authconfig --passminlen=15 --passminclass=4
```

Comment: Hello , that does not work. I've already tried this configuration that you've mentioned .. an error is displayed if i dont type password with all the 4 classes , but if i type a strong password like "Yk!l%!a!@La#a" which is 13 chars long , it let me change the password. I want that doesn't matter which chars are typed in the password .. it will always have to be at least 15 chars long...

Comment: I think that is the Credits that is making the problems... tried to find a way to disable it for good but no luck until now..

Answer (score 0):

After enabling pam_pwquality.so in `password-auth` and `system-auth`, set these parameters in `/etc/security/pwquality.so`.

```
minlen=15
dcredit=-1
ucredit=-1
ocredit=-1
lcredit=-1
```

Answer (score 0):

## RHEL7

1. add these values in /etc/security/pwquality.conf file
    minlen = 15
    ucredit = -1
    lcredit = -1
    ocredit = -1
    dcredit = -1
    minclass = #
                   #-is the number which you want to comply minimum types in 
                               password from all above defined classes

or 
use command "authconfig"

authconfig --enablereqlower --enablerequpper --enablereqdigit --enablereqother --passminlen=15 --update

## **RHEL5:**

1. password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=5 minlen=15 lcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 dcredit=-1 ocredit=-1

## **RHEL6:**

1. password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=5 dcredit=-1 ucredit=-1 ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1 minlen=15

===================

2. /etc/login.defs

PASS_MIN_LEN   15